# plotting only specific items in a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2, apply

I need to plot a series centrality values for users in a network over different years.

I'm only interested in plotting some, but I can't figure out how to do it and not all users appear every year.

Here's an example of the data. I'd like to be able to plot values for `"jhpedraza"`, for example, or even better, a string such as `users=c("jhpedraza","other user")`. Try `"char_arturo"` as well to get all the possible errors reproduced.

```
l=structure(list(`2009` = NULL, `2010` = NULL, `2011` = structure(c(0.0112191199212738, 
0.0119663133080306, 0.0112191199212738), .Names = c("jhpedraza", "didactech", 
"juanmanuelcorzo")), `2012` = structure(c(0.00520863174452703, 0.00543486753203931), 
.Names = c("jhpedraza", "lasillaenvivo")), `2013` = structure(c(0.00457122723603219, 
0.00362782800771276, 0.00342927774646075), .Names = c("jhpedraza", "milobeta", 
"char_arturo"))), split_type = "data.frame", split_labels = structure(list
(`format(Date, "%Y")` = c("2009", "2010", "2011", "2012",  "2013")), .Names = 
"format(Date, \"%Y\")", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L)), .Names = 
c("2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"))
```

Here´s an example of the plot I´m after. I managed to do it after a lot of data manipulation, but I am confident there´s a better solution: [image]

Comment: `sapply(l, i=1, function(x,i) x[i])` maybe this would work. This returns every first column of each data frame. you can change i in the sapply to get different columns. Meanwhile, this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Post what you want to plot and you will probably get an answer much easier than this.

Comment: thanks, your code addressing name instead of number works well: sapply(l, i="jhpedraza", function(x,i) x[i])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I opted for, using code from another SO question on lists:

```
ttt <- do.call(rbind, lapply(l, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

ttt$an <- rownames(ttt)

text <- as.character(ttt$an)

p2=as.data.frame(text) %>% separate(text, into = c("Year","User"))

ttt <- cbind(p2,ttt)

names(ttt) <- c("Year","User","PageRank","id") 

ids <- c("jhpedraza","lasillaenvivo") 

qqq <- subset(ttt,User %in% ids)


ggplot(qqq, aes(y = log(PageRank), x = Year, colour = as.factor(User))) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(aes(group = as.factor(User)),se=FALSE)+ggtitle("Centrality by Year") + labs(x="Year", y="Page Rank (log)") + labs(color='User')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` for this:

```
sapply(l, i="jhpedraza", function(x,i) x[i])
```

or by indices:

```
sapply(l, i=1, function(x,i) x[i])
```

Then you can use `plyr` package to get them inside one `data.frame` which can be used for plotting;

```
library(plyr)
df1 <- ldply(sapply(l, i=1, function(x,i) x[i]), data.frame)
```

Example plot:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=as.numeric(.id),y=X..i..),
                 data = df1, stat="identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=as.numeric(df1$.id), labels=as.numeric(df1$.id)) + 
  ggtitle("Example Plot") + labs(x="Year", y="Value") +
        theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#eff0f1",
                                  colour = "#eff0f1"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#eff0f1"))
```

---

## Update: How to deal with missing values within the list?

As you mentioned you have missing and null values, different columns, etc. in your list, this may help you:

```
df.completed <- plyr::ldply(lapply(l, Filter, f = Negate(is.null)),rbind)
```

This will give you a dataframe that has rows for each year (each dataframe in your list) and every column. Missing values of columns will be filled with `NA`.

*For your example dataset this would be the output:*

```
# > df.completed

#    .id   jhpedraza  didactech juanmanuelcorzo lasillaenvivo    milobeta char_arturo 
# 1 2011 0.011219120 0.01196631      0.01121912            NA          NA          NA 
# 2 2012 0.005208632         NA              NA   0.005434868          NA          NA 
# 3 2013 0.004571227         NA              NA            NA 0.003627828 0.003429278
```

And you can plot any of the columns like this (just change `jhpedraza` to desired column):

```
  ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=as.numeric(.id),y=jhpedraza),
           data = df.completed[complete.cases(df.completed$jhpedraza),], stat="identity") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=as.numeric(df1$.id), labels=as.numeric(df1$.id)) + 
    ggtitle("Example Plot") + labs(x="Year", y="jhpedraza") + theme_bw()
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! I get this error when I use the username, which i really need: 

> df1 <- ldply(sapply(l, i="jhpedraza", function(x,i) x[i]), data.frame)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : row names contain missing values

Comment: not every user has a value for every year and they are not in a particular order, that´s why the index won´t work...

Comment: I still don't have any problem while using `'jhpedraza'`. Provide a data.set that reproduces the error.

Comment: try "char_arturo"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier if you did this with tidyr and dplyr:

```
a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3

p2001 <- data.frame(a,b,c, yr = 2001)

a <- 2; b <- 1; c <- 3; e <- 3

p2002 <- data.frame(a,b,c,e, yr = 2002)

a <- 2; c <- 3; e <- 3; f <- 4

p2003 <- data.frame(a,c,e,f, yr = 2003)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
p.years <- bind_rows(p2001,p2002,p2003)

p.years.gathered <- gather(p.years,key = USER,value = VALUE,c(1,2,3,5,6))
```

Now you can plot by all users, or subset the dataframe into only the users you are interested in.  You'll just need to watch for which column has the yr after the bind_rows and adjust the gather accordingly.

Comment: I think the edits considerably changed the question I was asking. How can I share a file with the object I'm working on? I tried but it's too large and I think the example does not properly represent my question.